# Checking if cell is empty with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

`Nom_1` is the name of a cell in my worksheet, and is used in the following code.
Someimes that cell is left empty and I don't want the `NormInv` function to get called because it will return an error if the inputs are empty.

I get the error: `Unable to get the NormInv property of the WorksheetFunction class`

This leads me to believe my if statement is incorrect and it is allowing for the code to enter and execute even if `Nom_1` is empty.

```
If Not IsEmpty(Nom_1) Then
internal_1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.NormInv(Rnd(), N_1, Std_1)
End If
```

Am I correctly checking if the cell is empty?

Comment: have you tried `Range("Nom_1")`?

Comment: As far as avoiding empty cells, why aren't you just checking for either value <> "" or Len(value) > 0 ? If what you have isn't working.

Comment: `Barranka's` comment is the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Just Expanding on [Barranka's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355931/barranka) comment,

You need to make sure all cells with the names  `Nom_1` ,`N_1`,`Std_1`,`internal_1` exist in the workbook

then use `Range("Nom_1")` instead of `Nom_1`

```
Sub MyNormInv()

If Not IsEmpty(Range("Nom_1")) Then
Range("internal_1") = Application.WorksheetFunction.NormInv(Rnd(), Range("N_1"), Range("Std_1"))
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: IsEmpty Returns a Boolean value indicating whether a variable has been initialized. And only returns meaningful information for variants.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
 If Range(Nom_1).Value <> vbNullString Then
      internal_1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.NormInv(Rnd(), N_1, Std_1)
 End If
```

However, know that this will return False if you have a formula returning a zero length string in the cell. Even though the cell is not "empty" it will still be seen as blank because the value is "".

Comment: `Nom_1` is a named range not a variable, this won't work for the same reason the original question wouldn't work.